# Problems with displaying error validation messages

Tags: angular, validation

I really need your help. I'm trying to validate the registration form. To do this, I have fields in the form: `email`, `password`, `confirm-password`. For email validation, I use pattern for correctness, and for password I also use pattern (one big, one small letter and one number) and custom validator to check if passwords are the same. The fact is that if you enter the correct email, the field I have remains red, like with an error. And the custom validator for matching passwords doesn't work for me: I don't get the error that the passwords don't match. Please help me to solve this

template:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
    <mat-label>Email</mat-label>
    <input matInput formControlName="email">
    <mat-error *ngIf="registerForm.controls['email'].errors?.email">Invalid email</mat-error>
    <mat-error *ngIf="registerForm.controls['email'].errors?.minlength">At least 2 characters</mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
    <mat-label>Password</mat-label>
    <input matInput formControlName="password" (input)="onPasswordInput()" type="password">
    <mat-error *ngIf="registerForm.controls['password'].errors?.required">Field can't be empty</mat-error>
    <mat-error *ngIf="registerForm.controls['password'].errors?.minlength">At least 2 characters</mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
    <mat-label>Confirm password</mat-label>
    <input matInput formControlName="confirm_password" (input)="onPasswordInput()" type="password">
    <mat-error *ngIf="registerForm.controls['confirm_password'].errors?.required">Confirm password</mat-error>
    <mat-error *ngIf="registerForm.controls['confirm_password'].invalid || !registerForm.controls['confirm_password'].errors?.required">Password don't match</mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>
```

component:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
   this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
 email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2), Validators.email, Validators.pattern('^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\\d)[a-zA-Z\\d]{3,}$') ]],
 password: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2), Validators.pattern(`^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\\d)[a-zA-Z\\d]{6,}$`)]],
 confirm_password: ['', [Validators.required]]
 }, {validator: passwordMatchValidator})
}

get email () {return this.registerForm.get('email')}
get password() { return this.registerForm.get('password'); }
get confirm_password() { return this.registerForm.get('confirm_password'); }

onPasswordInput() {
if (this.registerForm.hasError('passwordDismatch'))
  this.registerForm.setErrors([{'passwordDismatch': true}]);
else
  this.registerForm.setErrors(null);
}
```

password_validator

```
import {AbstractControl, ValidationErrors, ValidatorFn} from "@angular/forms";
export let passwordMatchValidator: ValidatorFn;
passwordMatchValidator = (formGroup: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
if (formGroup.get('password')?.value === formGroup.get('confirm_password')?.value) {
  return null;
   } else {
    return {passwordDismatch: true}
   }
}
```

Comment: Is the password match validator working fine? Cuz I guess you need to return the validator function, too.

Comment: @MinaSoleimanzadeh Can you show please how to fix it? I will be wery grateful

Comment: Sure. Try this: export function passwordMatchValidator (): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
    if (formGroup.get('password')?.value === formGroup.get('confirm_password')?.value) {
  return null;
   } else {
    return {passwordDismatch: true}
   }
}
}

Comment: @MinaSoleimanzadeh, it doesn't works((( Can you help me to create validation? I will owe you

Comment: @GRD, Thanks, i have last question. How to reset validation after sending form? Because my inputs after sending are red and valid

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example of things you need to change: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-form-field-mbbjtp

Your email validator is not working as it should (by showing red-lines error when there is none) because your regex is wrong. You don't need it, since you already added Validator.email anyway.

Your password <-> confirm password validation wasn't working due to mistakes in your onPasswordInput method.

Comment: Thank you) According to your example, I had a lot of errors with underscores, probably because of the Angular version (I'm 13), but according to your concept and example, I solved this problem)